# Unable to view local geoserver in that dropdown menu of Open Geosuite?

Tags: geoserver, geoprocessing, boundless-suite, web-service, geoexplorer

I'm using GeoExplorer(Web Map Client) in OpenGeo Suite 4.5 version. I use to upload the layers from my LocalGeoserver by clicking on Add Layers Button. But now i'm unable to view my local geoserver in that dropdown menu.

How can I troubleshoot this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Please check your WMS GetCapabilities response. If you cannot add layers usually the cause is that WMS GetCapabilities output is broken because of e.g. a misconfigured layer.

Comment: im able to add layers from other sources like remote geoserver, other base layers,wms layers etc., but im unable to add layers from my local geoserver.. if i'm clicking on local geoserver it is disbled automatically...